# Tag Air-Compressor Used for Multiple ? Types

Tags: discussion

Looking at the tags, I see that the tag [air-compressor](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-compressor) is used for both and **AC Compressor** (possible tag *ac-compressor*) and for an **Air-Compressor** (as in to pump up a tire). I suggest we separate these type questions out into two tags as I have suggested here, or I guess we could just change the tag on the questions to the **ac** tag which is the catch-all for the system in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say we delete the tag all together, it's used 6 times 4 incorrectly and 2 correctly. Even on the two correct uses it doesn't seem relevant to the site.